# Text Wrapping when printing DataGrid? .Net

Tags: c#, .net, printing, datagrid, word-wrap

I'm trying to print a DataGrid in a windows forms app and when the width of the columns is set (it's customizable) too narrow to fit the text it just truncates the text instead of wrapping it. Is there a property in DataGrid that sets text wrapping?

I've added some code to perhaps help with diagnosis of the issue.

```
private void PrintRow(PointF location, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        PointF curLocation = location;

        //Measure the height of one row
        SizeF charSize = g.MeasureString(MEASURE_CHAR.ToString(), this.Grid.Font);
        float rowHeight = charSize.Height + CELL_PADDING * 2;

        //Print the vertical gridline on the left side of the first cell
        //Note that we only print the vertical gridlines down to the bottom 
        //of the last printed row
        int maxRowsOnPage = (int)Math.Floor(e.MarginBounds.Height / rowHeight);            
        int rowsRemaining = this.Grid.Rows.Count - _curRowIdx;
        int rowsToPrint = Math.Min(maxRowsOnPage, rowsRemaining);
        float bottom = e.MarginBounds.Top + (rowsToPrint * rowHeight);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, curLocation.X, e.MarginBounds.Top, curLocation.X, bottom);

        DataGridViewRow row = this.Grid.Rows[_curRowIdx];
        foreach (QueryField field in _fields)
        {                
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                //Exit early if this is not the correct cell
                if (this.Grid.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex].HeaderText != field.FieldLabel) continue;                    

                //Calculate where we need to draw the next cell
                int maxChars = field.MaxLength > 0 ? field.MaxLength : field.FieldLabel.Length;
                SizeF maxSize = g.MeasureString(string.Empty.PadLeft(maxChars, MEASURE_CHAR), this.Grid.Font);
                RectangleF boundingRect = new RectangleF(curLocation, maxSize);                    

                //Make sure we don't overshoot the right margin
                if (boundingRect.Left >= e.MarginBounds.Right)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (boundingRect.Right > e.MarginBounds.Right)
                {
                    boundingRect.Width = boundingRect.Width - (boundingRect.Right - e.MarginBounds.Right);
                }

                //Get the field value
                string fieldValue = string.Empty;
                if (cell.Value != null)
                {
                    fieldValue = cell.Value.ToString();
                }

                //Draw the field value                    
                g.DrawString(fieldValue, this.Grid.Font, Brushes.Black, (RectangleF)boundingRect, sf);

                curLocation.X += boundingRect.Width;
                curLocation.X += CELL_PADDING;

                //Print the vertical gridline between this cell and the next
                if (boundingRect.Right <= e.MarginBounds.Right)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, curLocation.X, e.MarginBounds.Top, curLocation.X, bottom);                       
                }

                //Move the current location to the next position
                curLocation.X += CELL_PADDING;
            }
        }

        //Draw the top gridline                 
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, curLocation.X, e.MarginBounds.Top);

        //Draw the bottom gridline     
        curLocation.Y += charSize.Height;                
        curLocation.Y += CELL_PADDING;
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, curLocation.Y, curLocation.X, curLocation.Y);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this thread. Someone with the exact same problem. Hope it helps!

[How to Wrap text in a text box column of datagrid in windows application.](http://tinyurl.com/qyge5z)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It was indeed most helpful and led me to fixing my issue. Sorry it took so long to mark as answered. =)